# Can we define an xsd with same named element with different attributes, Will this be a valid xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I want to merge two xsd's having the same namespace and element name but differnet attributes:

```
<s:schema ......>
<s:element name="CreateStudent">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ID" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FirstName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LastName" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>


<s:element name="CreateStudent">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ID" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FirstName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LastName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="MiddleName" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
</s:schema>
```

Comment: In this scenario you can't do it, but you could only if the `element` will declared within another complex type.

Comment: actually I can't have any addition to it as these are the xsds generated by two different  webservice wsdl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can't have two global element declarations with the same name and target namespace, and different content

...but you *can* have the same XML tag with different content. There are at least 2 ways that I can think of

1. Make the middleName attribute optional
2. Make the complex type of createStudent global. Create another complexType that extends the first and adds the extra attribute 'middleName'. Then use an xsi:type attribute in the XML to identify which type you want to validate against.

Option 1 will always allow createStudent without the middleName attribute.
Option 2 requires a change in the XML to identify the type.
Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't have two global element declarations with the same name and target namespace, and different content.